# Restful Webservice -file download

Tags: rest

When I want to download text file(name is demo.txt) using RestFul WebService and jersy and access it via   then I got the following error:
HTTP Status 500 - c:\demo.txt (The system cannot find the file specified) while I have demo.txt in C: drive
my code is:

```
@Path("/file")
public class FileService {

@GET
@Path("/download")
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response getFile(){
    File file=new File("c:\\demo.txt");
    ResponseBuilder builder=Response.ok((Object)file);
    builder.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"test1.txt\"");
    return builder.build();
}
}
```

Please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was going around the same issue few days ago.
The best thing to do is convert the file in a byte [], something like

byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

where 'is' is the input stream object of the file you want to download and then replace your code like this :

```
@Path("/file")
public class FileService {

@GET
@Path("/download")
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response getFile(){
    ResponseBuilder builder=Response.ok((Object)buffer);
    builder.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"test1.txt\"");
    return builder.build();
}
}
```

This works. try and let me know.